# Is there a way to watch for changes some files inside a directory?

Tags: ocaml, ml

I want to watch for changes in some files and do something on them when this happens

Comment: You should specify the context in which you want to do this ... from an ocaml program?

Comment: Alternatively, you can also write your own OCaml module for doing this -- something simple that just creates a new thread which polls files looking at their last modified time

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention what platform you want this to work on. Doing this in a nice way (without polling) has not been standardized across platforms (the way that reading and writing files has). So there's no simple platform-independent solution using just standard OCaml libraries.

There are individual mechanisms for particular platforms. By googling I found kqueue for BSD and macOS, inotify for Linux. If you happen to be on Linux, there are inotify wrappers in OPAM: https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/inotify/